# rc-datepicker DatePickerInput icons not appearing

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I am using [rc-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-datepicker) within my app and I have imported the following into my code:

```
import { DatePickerInput } from 'rc-datepicker';
rc-datepicker/lib/style.css
```

For some reason, both the calendar and clear icons are not appearing within my `DatePickerInput` field as shown in the example [here](https://rawgit.com/buildo/react-semantic-datepicker/master/examples/build/index.html).

I am using the code [here](https://github.com/buildo/rc-datepicker/blob/master/examples/DatePickerInput.example) for DatePickerInput.example:

```
<div className='ui input'>
          <DatePickerInput
            displayFormat='DD/MM/YYYY'
            returnFormat='DD/MM/YYYY'
            showOnInputClick
            placeholder='Date'
            iconClassName='calendar icon'
          />
</div>
```

I would've assumed that the `iconClassName='calendar icon'` would solve this issue but it doesn't.

All works fine but don't know the reason why the two rightmost icons (calendar and x) are not appearing?

Answer (score 0):

For others just in case someone else faces this issue as unfortunately the actual doco didn't make this clear but the code used as part of the example found [here](https://github.com/buildo/rc-datepicker/blob/master/examples/examples.js) helped me.

Specifically, the `onClear={this.onClear}` call was required as seen here:

```
onClear = () => this.setState({ datePickerDate: null })

  <DatePickerInput
      displayFormat='DD/MM/YYYY'
      returnFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
      className='my-react-component'
      onChange={(jsDate, dateString) => this.setState({ datePickerInputDate: dateString })}
      showOnInputClick
      placeholder='placeholder'
      locale='en'
      onClear={this.onClear}
    />
```